# Apply validation for form fields client side with angular

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs

I am writing a simple form, where I want to save the form result into an array, having both the first name and last name updated, if either or both fields are left empty it should throw an alert message. And the array should not store empty values and I wanted to handle this on the client side. I am kind of confused on how to keep a check on the input values before storing them.
Here is the code snippet: https://jsbin.com/guduwakeji/edit?html,js,output

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ele = [];
  $scope.updateDetails = function(ele) {
    if (!ele.firstname && !ele.lastname) {
      alert("Ele cannot be empty");
    } else {
      ele.push({
        'firstname': '',
        'lastname': ''
      });
      alert(ele.firstname + "  " + ele.lastname);
    }
    console.log(ele);
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="formCtrl">
    <div>
      First Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="ele.firstname">
      </br>
      Last Name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="ele.lastname">
      <br/>
      <input type="button" value="Submit" ng-click="updateDetails(ele)">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please add the code in question itself.

Comment: use `ng-pristine`,  `ng-dirty` ,`ng-valid`,  `ng-invalid`

Answer (score 1):

use this code

i figure out this way to validate your form

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('formCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.ele={};
    $scope.updateDetails = function(ele){
    if(ele.firstname &&  ele.lastname)
     { console.log(ele);}
      else{
        alert("empty field not allowed");
      }
    };

});
```

Comment: Yes, this also works for me. Thank you. But I have this doubt, we can also use required attribute in the input field right? Along with the model validation.

Comment: its not working because its not html form required is only work with html form hope you got it